# Test a range with Excel

Tags: excel

Let's suppose an excel file composed of three cells:

```
A1 : 1
A2 : 1
A3: A1+A2
```

Is there a way to continuously vary, by dragging the mouse for example, the number displayed in A1, between 1 and 1000, in order to be able to test and visualize the results in A3?

Comment: Add a scrollbar control to the sheet and link it to A1

Answer (score -1):

Can't see any OnMouseMove events for workbook or worksheet, so the event is SheetSelectonChange, just use arrow keys or click about.

A1 will change to a random number between 1 and 1000
A2 has value of 1
A3 = A1 + A2

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetSelectionChange(ByVal Sh As Object, _
 ByVal Target As Excel.Range)
    Dim rndNumber As Integer
    rndNumber = Int((1000 - 1 + 1) * Rnd + 1)
    Range("A1").Value = rndNumber
    Calculate
End Sub
```